# can iconic wide live tile flip

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

how do i create a wide live tile and it will flip and change? i search for it and most of the result does not meet my requirement.

this will create a wide tile, but how do i flip it?

```
IconicTileData TileData = new IconicTileData()
{
   Title = "[title]",
   Count = [count],
   WideContent1 = "[1st row of content]",
   WideContent2 = "[2nd row of content]",
   WideContent3 = "[3rd row of content]",
   SmallIconImage = [small Tile size URI],
   IconImage = [medium/wide Tile size URI],
   BackgroundColor = [.NET color type of Tile]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The only way for you can achieve your goal is to use a flip tile and render the images yourself so they look like an iconic tile.